# What are the tools/sdks available to aid in HTML generation?

Tags: c#, java, .net, gwt, html-generation

I want to write a C# program which can generate a series of HTML pages based on some data grabbed from an external database. Are there any .NET based SDK which enables me to do the HTML generation? Maybe I am searching on the wrong keywords, but can't seem to find a simplistic, comprehensive answer to this. Just wondering as well, is the Google Web Toolkit an answer to my problem IF I use Java instead? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I would avoid server-side HTML generation, and opt for client-side templates.

There are many options when it comes to client-side templating, but [`jquery-tmpl`](http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/) is becoming a the standard template engine for jQuery.

If you want this to tie into your data easily, consider using [MVC3](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3) with [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/), as demonstrated here: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM08